# How to reference a function on an other script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game and I can't reference the function from an other script.

I have a first script where there is a collision function. And I have a second one where stats are applied.

How can I apply damage when `OnCollisionEnter` prox?

```
public PlayerData playerData;

void Start()
{
    playerData = FindObjectOfType<PlayerData>();
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        PlayerData.HPmodifiers(int -1);
    }
}
```

And the `PlayerData` script looks like this:

```
public int CurrentHealth = 10;
public int MaxHealth = 10;

public void HPmodifiers(int Damage)
{
    CurrentHealth -= Damage;
}
```

Comment: `PlayerData` is your className, and `playerData` (small p) is your variable (reference) name. Try  `playerData.HPmodifiers(-1);`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a **common misspell** :), **PlayerData** is your class and **playerData** is your reference var to the found object.

Also if you do int -1 in your function call the **health will actually go up** because of the damage being subtracted.

I would also **remove the **hardcoded value**** and make it show in the inspector using **[SerializeField]**

****playerData** could also be a private reference** so that it doesn't show in the inspector (which could be confusing) since inspector input will be discarded in Start() and I assume no other scripts are accessing it

```cs
[SerializeField] private int damage = 1; 
playerData.HPmodifiers(damage);
```

You can also visit
https://learn.unity.com/ , it's a AMAZING resource full of free courses and short tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the component and call the methods through it.

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        if (other.collider.TryGetComponent(out PlayerData pData))
        {
            pData.HPmodifiers(-1);
        }
    }
}
```